# How can I access the commandline screen from Vim on a Mac terminal?

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim

I was on vim once and I accidentally pressed some keys, then another screen popped up with a message along the lines of "You found the console screen! To exit, press :q!" I'm trying to access this screen again, but I don't remember what key combination it was.

I do know for sure that it was not `:term` or any other command that started with `:`, it was just some key presses. I tried looking this up on the internet and on the vim docs, but the only results I got were things like `:term`. If you know anything at all about this, please leave a comment or a reply. Thanks!

Edit: the exact message it gives is `You discovered the command-line window! You can close it with ":q"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show it again by typing `q:` in normal mode. See `:help q:`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Was half expecting no one to see my question because i'm a new user with basically no reputation. This worked for me!

Comment: All questions have the same visibility, regardless of the user's reputation.